# How to fix error when running linear regression models with fractional exponents?

Tags: r, lapply, lm, summary

I am trying to run a linear regression model with fractional exponents for about 19000 columns of data, but I keep getting this error:

```
 Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

The basic linear regression function y~x works perfectly, but the linear regression function I want to try, y~ x + y^(1/3) gives me the above error.

I've tried removing all the NA columns using na.exclude/na.omit but they do not work. I had to do use na.omit() from an original set of data for the basic linear regression model, but the new dataset doesn't work with the new linear regression model.

Here is my function:

```r
reg1 <- lapply(1:19914, function (x) summary(lm(Everything.ver2[,x+1] ~ Everything.ver2[,"VWRETD"] + I(Everything.ver2[,x+1]^(1/3))))$coefficients)
```

I expect it to run a regression using the new model, but it instead gives me the error above. I would greatly appreciate help!

Comment: Are you dividing by any 0?

Comment: I don't think I am. My model is y~x+y^(1/3), simplified.

Comment: Could  you share a sample of your data with `dput`?

Comment: Sure. Here is a sample of the last 17 columns. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oKxa4IntRaFouNCtr_iESQ4DSgbNiW8c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have `y` in the right side and in the left side ? That's very strange...

Comment: In the sample, I am regressing the numbered columns with the column "VWRETD

Comment: It is because I had to merge datasets and it ended up being on the right. I did not make the change because I assume it wouldn't be a problem, which wasn't for the basic linear regression model.

Comment: You are taking the 1/3 power of negative numbers.  This is mathematically possible, but not numerically possible, because R calculates such powers as `exp((1/3)*log(x))`, and `log(x)` gives `NaN` for negatives.

Comment: Your sample doesn't give an error.  Probably one column in your list of 19000 has no values that are positive and not NA.

Comment: Thanks for responding. If all values are negative in a column, it wouldn't work?

Comment: The problem was that there were 3 columns of bad data that I needed to seek out. What I did was run the linear regression several times over ranges until I could close in on the columns that were the issue. Thanks for the suggestion that there was a column that was incorrect. I wonder why the normal linear regression model allowed the three "bad" columns. I call them "bad" because I honestly don't know what was wrong with them.